# Is the switch representation for this logic wrong?

Tags: logic-gates

In an old text I came across the following for A’B+AB’ logic:

[image]

It seems the bottom logic gates follows the logic but Im bit confused about the switch representation. Isn’t it wrong?

Comment: flip both switches upward and examine the circuit ... then flip both downward

Comment: To me switch represents A’B’+AB. Am I wrong?

Comment: They simultaneously touch either A’B’ or AB

Comment: @cm64 You can put the switches any way you want, but unless the combination matches a part of the equation, then the output is low.  eg A'B' output is low, but when switches are up (A'B) then the output is high.

Comment: `They simultaneously touch either A’B’ or AB` ... no they don't ... look again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The switch is mostly correct, it only doesn't account for the case when both inputs to the "OR" gate are true.
If you read it when both switches are up, then you get A'B. Or when both switches are down you get AB'.  <s>So I guess the switch representation is more like an XOR gate fed by two AND gates.</s>

Comment: But the  case given is wrong isnt it? It shows A’B’+AB

Comment: @cm64 strictly speaking, yes because, as I stated in my answer, the switches do not handle the case of both inputs being true at the same time.  However electrically it will perform the same.

Comment: The case given by the switches is not wrong, it's just one example of four possible configurations. In this case A'B+AB'=0

Answer (score 2):

The switches are correct. The circuit will only be closed when the left switch is at \$\overline{A}\,(A=0)\$ and the right switch is at \$B\,(B=1)\$ or when the left switch is at \$A\,(A=1)\$ and the right switch is at \$\overline{B}\, (B=0)\$, thus \$\overline{A}B + A\overline{B}\$. The configuration in the drawing is showing \$A=0, B=0\$.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's a bad example.  It is only missing V+, ground ,  a current loop and no voltages.

If there was a  voltage and a series light bulb across each pole, you have two 3 way switches or two OR toggle switches. which are wired as Y= (AB!+A!B) =  ...

- with Y=0 a metastable race condition for the logic gates and glitches to 1 during any input transition!

  - very bad unless you want this glitch.

Whereas, either switch can turn ON the light or OFF with a current   around the poles.

So it is lacking assumptions, the precursor to Murphy's Law.

But this reminds me. An XOR gate (with 10us delay added on one side) made me an excellent ZCS for 60 Hz square wave to both inputs  of XOR   in ‘75 with pulse transformer glitch trigger to Triac.